# Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: Resource temporarily unavailable (g-io-error-quark, 27)

Tags: centos, systemd, d-bus

Every time I restart a service (e.g. `service exim restart`, run as root), I get the following error message:

> `Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: Resource temporarily unavailable (g-io-error-quark, 27)`

The `dbus-daemon` also has a 100% CPU usage.

The output of `journalctl -r -p err -b` shows an extreme amount - `6979` entries - of the following error:

```
pam_systemd(crond:session): Failed to connect to system bus: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

There are also 5033 session files. Theses are when a session is made via ssh, these are supposed to be deleted automatically, but I'm hesitant to delete them myself

```
ls -1 /var/run/systemd/sessions/ | wc -l
5033
```

What is the cause and how can I prevent this?

- CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

Answer (score 1):

this is a bug of systemd-logind && dbus-daemon，relate to https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1961

because crond always call  pam_systemd, and pam_systemd always call systemd-logind to create a session scope use dbus-daemon , but sometimes dbus-daemon alway do not work , so we should better make crond do not call systemd-logind

stop systemd-logind also will not influence ssh , just can not use session cgroup

```
sudo sed -i -e '/^[^#]*pam_systemd.so/ s/^/#&/g' /etc/pam.d/*
sudo systemctl mask systemd-logind
sudo systemctl stop systemd-logind
```